# How to get DocValue by document ID in Lucene 7+?

Tags: solr, lucene

I'm adding a DocValue to a document with

```
doc.add(new BinaryDocValuesField("foo",new BytesRef("bar")));
```

To retrieve that value for a specific document with ID `docId`, I call

```
DocValues.getBinary(reader,"foo").get(docId).utf8ToString();
```

The `get` function in BinaryDocValues is supported up to [**Lucene 6.6**](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_6_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/BinaryDocValues.html), but for [**Lucene 7.0**](https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/BinaryDocValues.html) and up it does not seem to be available anymore.

So, **how do I get the DocValue by document ID in Lucene 7+** (without having to iterate over `BinaryDocValues` / `DocIdSetIterator`, and without having to re-get `BinaryDocValues` and use `advanceExact` every time) ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Theory

Doc values are Lucene's column-stride field value storage. Doc values were intended to be quite fast for random access at query time for faceting and sorting purposes. 
The following issue [LUCENE-7407](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-7407) switches access pattern from random-access to an iterator. Because an iterator API is a much more restrictive access pattern than an arbitrary random access API, this change gives Lucene more freedom and power to use aggressive compression and other optimizations:

- reduction of disc space usage in case of sparse data
- better compression ratio and speed of decoding of doc values, even in the non-sparse case
- remove special column of missing values(getDocsWithField) and thread local codec readers

You can read about this change in the following blogs:

- [Doc values as iterators](http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2017/03/apache-lucene-70-is-coming-soon.html)
- [Sparse versus dense document values with Apache Lucene](https://www.elastic.co/blog/sparse-versus-dense-document-values-with-apache-lucene)

## Practice

In practice this change causes performance degradation in some cases, for example [SOLR-9599](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-9599). In major case(faceting and sorting) an iterative API is OK with proper usage and, even more, allows to perform some optimizations.
In fact there are a lot of cases where this API is not a good solution. All these cases were discarded as an incorrect usage(the same problem we had in java word with sun.misc.Unsafe).

In fact, `org.apache.lucene.index.DocValuesIterator#advanceExact` is quite fast and has similar performance and complexity in case of some implementations.

Comment: Another great answer - thank you very much for the clarifications.

Comment: We encountered the mentioned performance degradation (it gets progressively worse as segment size increases), which prompted https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-8374 - it does not change the API, so one still needs to request an iterator, but the speed does not deteriorate with larger segments.